# Find normaliser of $S_{n-1}$ in $S_n$.

Tags: group-theory, proof-verification, symmetric-groups

I have tried it in the following way.
Let $g\in N(S_{n-1})$.
$(1,2,....,n-1)$ is in $S_{n-1}$.
Now $$g(1,2,....,n-1)g^{-1} = (g(1),g(2),....,g(n-1))\in S_{n-1}$$  Therefore, $g(1)$, $g(2)$, $\ldots$, $g(n-1)$ none of them can be $n$, i.e $g$ fixes $n$.
 Therefore $g\in S_{n-1}$.
Hence normaliser of $S_{n-1}$ in $S_n$ is $S_{n-1}$.

Is it correct? Is there any other way to find it?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: Your proof should be correct.